# key Server indicated failure for sending gpg keys

Tags: server, gnupg, pgp

Server indicated failure for sending keys

```
debian@osboxes:~/$ gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --send-keys 8D32FF6AEEB7BA37
gpg: sending key 8D32FF6AEEB7BA37 to hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: keyserver send failed: Server indicated a failure
gpg: keyserver send failed: Server indicated a failure
```

I tried to generate gpg keys for myself. I do not know if I did correct or not when I do

```
debian@osboxes:~/$ gpg --list-keys
/home/debian/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
-------------------------------
pub   rsa3072 2020-06-11 [SC] [expires: 2022-06-11]
      980265BC6D8749B0B57526888D32FF6AEEB7BA37
uid           [ultimate] Political Science 
sub   rsa3072 2020-06-11 [E] [expires: 2022-06-11]
```

Comment: I used a graphical tool based on instructions here https://askubuntu.com/a/100313/992730 this has worked and in GUI I see my key id as  EEB7BA37 some how on command line it was not clear  what is the key id. They key string is in last charachters of the string pub

Answer (score 1):

Enter the command as follows. If it doesn't work, consider looking into any firewall/proxy you may have running that may be interfering with the connection.

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --send-key 8D32FF6AEEB7BA37980265BC6D8749B0B57526888D32FF6AEEB7BA37
```

This will ensure that port 80 gets used which is most assuredly open.