# What is the best "File Shredder" to remove files from my system.

Tags: security, files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete file(s) in secure manner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57572/how-to-delete-files-in-secure-manner)

I need a program to permanently remove files from my system similar to [File Shredder](http://www.fileshredder.org/)

Answer (score 10):

There is a tool on Linux called "wipe", and you can install it by the following command:

```
    sudo apt-get install wipe
```

This allows you to securely render a file you want deleted unrecoverable (via reasonable attempts at recovery). Here is the [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wipe) for wipe if you want to read any information on it. It is also a good idea to read the man page of wipe straight after installation. This is done by:

```
    man wipe
```

Answer (score 3):

There's also a tool called *BleachBit*, which you can find in Ubuntu Software Center.
Not only does it wipe free space but also has quite a lot of options for cleaning up the system.