# How to delete files irreversibly?

Tags: filesystem, files, delete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete file(s) in secure manner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57572/how-to-delete-files-in-secure-manner)

I read that the files which are permanently deleted still can be recovered with some utilities and methods.
I want to know how can I delete those permanently deleted files so that they can not be recovered any more, with any methods and any utility? Never ever again.
And in the future what should we use to delete files forever?