# How to shred a folder?

Tags: command-line, files, shredding

I want a command to shred completely the contents of a folder/directory (which may be inside folders/directories).
Also please explain the command.

Comment: Define "shred".  If you just mean what the `shred` command does, then there's your answer.

Comment: Very closely related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/57572/how-to-delete-files-in-secure-manner

Comment: @psusi- by shred i mean delete file beyond recovery. i was using the shred command but as that was applicable only to files i wanted a similar command to delete folders and files within it.

Comment: Which one does the job perfectly `shred` or `secure-delete`?

Comment: both of the solutions work for me but i think the srm one is easier.

Comment: For other users that stumble here, beware the `shred` **is not as effective as you think** because modern file systems and hardware do not overwrite data in place, but instead journal the changes, or move it around for wear-levelling. Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27027/how-do-i-recursively-shred-an-entire-directory-tree

Answer (score 35, accepted):

1. Install the package `secure-delete`.
2. Use the command `srm -r pathname` to remove your folder and files.

The default settings are for 38 (!!!) passes of overwrites which is extreme overkill imho (see more info about this [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120409055439/http://www.anti-forensics.com/disk-wiping-one-pass-is-enough)).

For my usage, I only want a single pass of random data so I use `srm -rfll pathname`.

If you want to create a right-click option in the GUI for files and folders, use gnome-actions to call a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if dialog=`zenity --window-icon=warning --question --title="Secure Delete" --no-wrap --text="Are you sure you want to securely delete:\n\n     $1\n\nand any other files and folders selected? File data will be overwritten and cannot be recovered."` 
then /usr/bin/srm -fllrv "$@"| zenity --progress --pulsate --text="File deletion in progress..." --title="Secure Delete" --auto-close
fi
```

If you want more paranoid settings be sure to modify the above script.

Comment: `-f  fast (and insecure mode): no /dev/urandom, no synchronize mode`.       
`-l  lessens the security (use twice for total insecure mode)`. could you please explain these two things. 38 overwrites is default how do these affect the '38' value. and why `l` two times in `-rfll`

Comment: OK, the whole default process is:

1 pass with 0xff (a zero wipe), 5 random passes with /dev/urandom is used for a secure RNG if available, 27 passes with special values defined by Peter Gutmann, another 5 random passes from /dev/random. Then rename the file to a random value & truncate the file. IIRC, /dev/random is considered a better random number generation system. Using -fll we skip the 1+5+27+5 passes and substitute with a single pass of random data, possibly from a less "truly random" generator.

Comment: @Ashu shortened from the man page (Debian Jessie) for srm; `(frist) -l: only two passes`, `(second) -l: only one pass`. For others, `-f: fast (Non-secure random bits)` and `-r: recursive`. I also highly suggest `-v: verbose`. I would also suggest running this in a `screen` instance, it can take quite a while on a lot of data.

Comment: I have replaced `/usr/bin/srm -fllrv` with `bleachbit -s`

Comment: You may use Bleachbit's shredder with 'bleachbit -s' as an alternative which is fast and much more widely known.

Answer (score 15):

For files not directories, here's a more simple way instead of `-exec shred -u {} \;` type of way:

```
cd to your directory.
```

then

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 shred -fuzv -n 48
```

this does 48 passes recursively to the current directory you `cd`'ed into.

Hope this helps some.

Comment: Adding '-print0' to find and '-0' to xargs? Directories may have whitespace in their names.

Comment: Good answer but Why do you use xargs?? I don't understand xargs.

Answer (score 3):

`sudo apt install wipe`

`$ wipe -rfi dir/*`

where the flags used:

`-r – tells wipe to recurse into subdirectories
-f – enables forced deletion and disable confirmation query
-i – shows progress of deletion process`

Comment: For the sake of transparency, wipe has been unmaintained since 2009 and therefore perhaps should be used with caution: https://sourceforge.net/projects/wipe/files/

Comment: Wipe Version: 0.24-7 provided in Ubuntu Impish was last updated 2016 on https://github.com/berke/wipe

Answer (score 2):

Shred works only on files. You need to shred the files in the dir/subdirs first and then remove the directories. try

```
find [PATH_TO_DIR]
```

and make sure you only see the files you want to delete

```
find [PATH_TO_DIR] -exec shred -u {} \;
```

then remove the dirs with

```
rm -rf [PATH_TO_DIR]
```

Comment: can u please explain `{} \;` . also somewhere elsi i had seen the same command as your but it was `'{}' \;` what is the difference between the two??

Comment: Since shred doesn't work on directories, how about adding the option -type f to the find commands?

Comment: @ andol : yeah i was thinking of that..

Comment: Cant explain it any better than the find man page ....
the {} and \; are part of the -exec option of the find.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use something similar to this:

```
find dir -type f -exec shred -fuz {} +
rm -rf dir
```

First command finds only files and passes them to shred (as many at once as possible - no need to start a new shred process for every file like \; does). Finally, remove the directories too.

Answer (score 0):

I have inserted the following bash script for this purpose in my .bashrc

```
function rm2 {

  for var in $@
  do
  if [ -d $var ]
  then
     nohup $( /usr/bin/find "$var" -type f -exec  shred -n 2 -u -z -x {} \;;/bin/rm -rf "$var" ) & 
  else
    nohup /usr/bin/shred -x -n 2 -u -z "$var" & 
  fi
done
exit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this from Nautilus (aka 'Files' app), then you could use the [nautilus-wipe](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-wipe) package.

- `sudo apt-get install nautilus-wipe`

Once installed, there will be two new options when you right-click on a folder: `Wipe` and `Wipe available disk space`. Choosing `Wipe` on the folder will give further options (e.g. number of passes, fast mode, last pass with zeros).

Answer (score -1):

When I need to shred multiple files or an entire directory I simply use `shred -vzn 20 ./shredme/*.*` for example, which overwrites all files with any file extension in the "shredme" folder. Then you can use the standard rm -rf ./shredme command to remove the folder itself (or just right click and delete the folder) as all the data has been overwritten 20 times for this example.

I did a quick example of this with a bunch of duplicate images as an example.

[image: Terminal screenshot]