# How to delete sensitive data on Android phone?

Tags: filesystem, android

I want to sell an old Android phone. How can I delete sensitive data on my Android phone with a MicroSD card from within Ubuntu, in a secure manner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can erase SD card using a command line tool called [`shred` (manpage)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/shred)

You can also refer to this discussion in askubuntu.
[How to delete file(s) in secure manner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57572/how-to-delete-files-in-secure-manner)

OR

Here is a tutorial (but you don't need live cd, if you are on ubuntu) - http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15037/use-an-ubuntu-live-cd-to-securely-wipe-your-pcs-hard-drive/

For deleting everything on phone, Hard reset is OK. But I recommend flashing the original phone firmware. You can get instructions at [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/)

Comment: Is it established that any existing methods of overwriting data are sufficient to prevent any possible data recovery *on flash media?* Almost all the research in this areas applies specifically to magnetic hard disks.

Comment: I have reinstalled CyanogenMod on that phone. So that is really enough to delete all the data on the phone in a secure manner?

Answer (score 1):

You can try in terminal:

```
 shred –remove –iterations=<num> <file>
```

e.g. :
`cd` your memorycard name
`ls` (to list the files)
`shred -remove -iteration=50` yoursensitivedatafile name