# How to delete all the things off a hard drive seperately

Tags: 11.10

I need to delete all the files off my dying hard drive in Ubuntu v.11.10. If I could have a quick response that would be great because my computer is also dying.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather an odd question but I'll bite:

1. [Download and boot to Live CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest)
2. Choose "Try Ubuntu" when offered
3. Load up the Partition Editor (`gparted`) or the Disk Utility (`palimpsest`)
4. Format the drive.

If you are doing this for security reasons (you don't want the data recovered) see:

- [How to delete file(s) in secure manner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57572/how-to-delete-files-in-secure-manner)
  (and this should be done from the Live environment)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you write what you mean ?
You want to DELETE ALL YOUR FILES ??

well okay, first find out what device your harddisk is, be it /dev/sda or /dev/sdb or whatever. In the following example I persume it is /dev/sda (if it isn't, just modify my example)

type in a terminal:

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=8M

this will wipe your harddrive CLEAN  and therefore DELETES EVERYTHING !!

Comment: If you want it a bit more secure for forensic reasons: sudo dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/sda bs=8M