# How To Replace Deleted File Bytes With Random Bytes

Tags: disk, format, file-format, disk-utility, gnome-disk-utility

Let's assume that I "erased" some file named `important.txt`. This file is still exists on the hard drive (invisible attribute changed to true), so what I am trying to do is find the `important.txt` that I just "erased" (like with the `Recuva` program),
and then to replace its bytes with random bytes (i.e. delete `important.txt` permanently)
So I am Looking for software Like `Recuva`, but not For recovering, or maybe software that replaces the bytes of any deleted file that still exists.

I Just want to wipe "deleted files" permanently. Is there any software that can do that for me?

Comment: It would have been easier if you hadn't already deleted them: http://askubuntu.com/questions/57572/how-to-delete-files-in-secure-manner, Also check out BleachBit: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/bleachbit/

Comment: yes i know, i could use file shredder :/

Comment: Bleachbit "wipes free disk space (to hide previously deleted files for privacy and to improve compression of images)" according to the description, so that might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Bleachbit "wipes free disk space (to hide previously deleted files for privacy and to improve compression of images)" according to the description in the [Ubuntu Apps Directory](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/bleachbit/) so that might be useful.