# I'd like to destroy some data quickly and reliably. How?

Tags: files, security

So, long story short, I have some, er, [*sensitive*](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/spongebob/images/2/2c/RecipeForAKrabbyPatty.jpg) data that I'd like to protect from people trying to snoop around. Let's say it's in a folder on my desktop called `My Secrets`.

However, I'd like to retain some sort of method to destroy this data to make it unrecoverable, in such a way that it is impossible to recover and that there is no proof that this data even existed in the first place.

I'd like to be able to preserve my Ubuntu installation and any/all non-sensitive data, so a complete nuke (sadly) isn't an option.

How can I achieve this in Ubuntu?

Ideally, I'd also like to be able to trigger this deletion at the drop of a pin, from which point there is no stopping the (at the very least partial) destruction of my data. I'm also willing to use a solution that requires setup (for, say, any future data that needs storage).

Comment: May we assume you use rotating magnetic disks (HDD) as storage and no Flash memory (SSD, USB drives, SD cards, ...)?

Comment: @ByteCommander To make it easier, sure. But, ideally, I'd like a solution that works on anything.

Comment: Pfff, high maintenance much? I still think a sledgehammer is the ebst option.

Comment: @DavidCole-GrammarPolice I'd like to keep my functioning system.

Comment: On SSDs, you either need to use encryption starting from the very first second (your sensitive data may never have touched the raw disk) or you need to fiddle around with special ATA commands to make the SSD controller firmware perform a complete nuke of all flash cells of the entire device, including the spare ones. The SSD might also have hardware encryption, then it might be enough if the controller discards the old key and creates a new one.

Comment: The only thing that meets your requirement of almost immediate quick and securely irrecoverable deletion is setting up a strongly encrypted partition or container file (don't forget to encrypt swap too as well then) which allows overwriting its encryption header data to trash it. I think the LUKS stuff is designed for that, but don't remember that well...

Comment: @ByteCommander If that works and can grant plausible deniability... then we have a decent answer... maybe?

Comment: @KazWolfe - There is no such thing as "plausible deniability" lol

Comment: What about BleachBit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete file(s) in secure manner?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/57572/how-to-delete-files-in-secure-manner)

Comment: What is your threat model?  Are you trying to protect yourself from a snooping younger sibling or from a Three Letter Agency.  If it's a TLA, how much are they willing to break (I mean "bend") the law to retrieve the data.  Is Rubber hose cryptanalysis on the table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`shred` from GNU `coreutils` was specifically designed for this purpose.

From `man shred`:

> Overwrite the specified FILE(s) repeatedly, in order to make it harder
>   for even very expensive hardware probing to recover the data.

`shred` actually reads random bytes from `/dev/urandom` and overwrites the files content with those, at the end optionally overwrites the contents by zeroes (from `/dev/zero`). So if you want to reinvent the wheel, you can do this by hand but better to use `shred` which is optimized already for the task.

---

For example, for any given file `my_secured_file.txt`, you can do:

```
shred my_secured_file.txt
```

Here:

- `-v` for verbosity
- `-z` for overwriting the file with zeroes afterwards, to hide shredding
- `-n 5` is for number of iterations, default is 3

You can increase the number of iterations if you want although the default is enough or even remove the file (`-u`, `--remove`).

Check `man shred`.

---

As `shred` operates on files, for doing the operation on all files of a directory (recursively) e.g. `my_secret_dir`:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in my_secret_dir/**/*; do shred -vzn 5 -- "$f"; done
```

Or `find`:

```
find my_secret_dir -type f -exec shred -vzn 5 -- {} +
```

---

**Note:**

`shred` has the caveat that it can't work properly on the journaling, caching, RAID, compressed file systems. Quoting `man shred`:

> CAUTION: Note that shred relies on a very important assumption: that the file system overwrites data in place.  This is the
>   traditional way to do things, but many modern file system designs do
>   not satisfy this assumption.  The following  are  examples
>          of file systems on which shred is not effective, or is not guaranteed to be effective in all file system modes:
>
> - log-structured or journaled file systems, such as those supplied with AIX and Solaris (and JFS, ReiserFS, XFS, Ext3, etc.)
> - file systems that write redundant data and carry on even if some writes fail, such as RAID-based file systems
> - file systems that make snapshots, such as Network Appliance's NFS server
> - file systems that cache in temporary locations, such as NFS version 3 clients
> - compressed file systems
>
>   In the case of ext3 file systems, the above disclaimer applies (and shred is thus of limited effectiveness) only in data=journal
>     mode, which journals file data in addition to just metadata.  In both
>     the data=ordered (default) and data=writeback modes,
>        shred works as usual.  Ext3 journaling modes can be changed by adding the data=something option to the mount options for a particular
>     file system in the /etc/fstab file, as documented in the mount man
>     page (man mount).
>
>   In addition, file system backups and remote mirrors may contain copies of the file that cannot be removed, and that will allow a
>     shredded file to be recovered later.

---

In Ubuntu, if you are using `ext4` filesystem which is also a journaling filesystem, the journal mode is the default for metadata, not for data (`data=ordered` is the default), so you should get the expected result with `shred`-ing unless you changed the default.

---

As a side note, you can find the default filesystem options by:

```
sudo dumpe2fs -h /partition |& grep 'Filesystem features'
```

**Example:**

```
% sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda3 |& grep 'Filesystem features'
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
```

The `has_journal` indicates that this is a journaling FS and the default journal option(s) are:

```
% sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda3 |& grep 'Journal features'
Journal features:         journal_incompat_revoke
```

Both at once:

```
% sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda3 |& grep 'features' 
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Journal features:         journal_incompat_revoke
```

Comment: The `-u` option to delete (unlink) the file after shredding is probably more useful than using 5 passes instead of the default 3. Also `shred` has no recursive option and operates only on files, that means to delete everything in a nested directory tree, you must combine it with `find`.

Comment: It should also be noted that `shred` can only securely wipe a file if the mapping between file system blocks and hard disk is guaranteed to be constant. This is not the case on Flash storage like SSDs, USB drives or memory cards as well as hybrid HDD/SSD drives and possibly RAID drives or other mappings. Same goes for compressed file systems or devices that take snapshots. File systems that use caching or data journaling (store data to be written in a special journal file before actually writing it to the data area) may also leave intact data fragments behind after shredding.

Comment: @ByteCommander Edited.

Comment: The "theory" that you have to write to a disk or file system more then once has been debunked long ago - http://www.howtogeek.com/115573/htg-explains-why-you-only-have-to-wipe-a-disk-once-to-erase-it/ and http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/13674/is-it-possible-to-recover-data-on-a-zeroed-hard-drive. Please do not spread FUD =)

Comment: Nice, please note that ext3 and ext4 do *not* have data journaling on by default though (default is option `data=ordered`). They do only journal metadata.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Hmmm, thats for extreme pedant, anyway made an edit, check now.

Comment: @ByteCommander Thats correct, but i had to go through the source, couldn't depend on arcane `man shred`.

Answer (score -3):

Here's an off the wall suggestion: store the sensitive data *only* in an encrypted, password-locked cloud storage, with *no shortcut folder* in your computer (i.e. don't install Dropbox or similar, which creates a local mirror of the remote storage) -- just a bookmark in your browser.  When you want to remove evidence on your local system of the sensitive data, delete the bookmark and wipe the browser history (or, ideally, use a high security browser variant or setting that automatically secure wipes the history every time you close it).   Ten seconds or so, and there'll be no way for anyone to know where to start looking, short of a forensic level complete system search (extremely unlikely unless you're an international spy or child porn trafficker).

Comment: OP said they already stored the data in the disk!!

Comment: The "theory" that you have to write to a disk or file system more then once has been debunked long ago - http://www.howtogeek.com/115573/htg-explains-why-you-only-have-to-wipe-a-disk-once-to-erase-it/ and http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/13674/is-it-possible-to-recover-data-on-a-zeroed-hard-drive . Please do not spread FUD =) . Encryption is not completely reliable and there are multiple ways to crack it see - http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/security.png