# how to securely erase disk I am currently on?

Tags: partitioning, secure-erase

I am going to sell my notebook and want to erase my 256GB SDD before so that data cannot be restored under any circumstances.

Using tools like shred and dd I can do that with certain partitions which I am not currently running my OS from.

But since I only have one partition on my notebook, I am wondering how/which tool I can use to safely erase/overwrite the content?

Comment: Is the SSD an NVMe device or does it have a SATA interface? 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete file(s) in secure manner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57572/how-to-delete-files-in-secure-manner)

Comment: matigo how to I find that out?

Comment: You should not try to destroy the contents of your disk while you've booted to it. If you want to completely destroy everything, boot to a usb device and destroy it from there

Comment: If you open Terminal and type `lsblk`, you will see the layout for the storage devices. If your main storage device is something like `nvme0n1p1`, then it's an NVMe storage device. If you see `/dev/sda`, then it's using a SATA interface (even if it's in an m.2 slot). If you are using an NVMe disk, then you can (probably) wipe your disk in a half-second without killing it with a full `shred` or `dd` sequence ...

Comment: "under any circumstances" ?  Suggestion... Boot from live usb. Use gparted to delete the partitions, add a new partition formatted to ntfs or exfat. Use shred to fill the card completely with zeros: single pass. Install the new o/s. To verify, you will need to create another live usb specific to the forensics environment, then see what residual fragments may be possibly recoverable. Expect this process to consume days of time.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot sit on the chair while sawing the legs off. Similarly, a partition you want to wipe should not be in use.

Start a live session using a live USB or DVD, or alternatively, boot into a recovery prompt, and shred the partition from there.

Consider whether shredding is worthy the time and trouble. Reformatting the partition or erasing partitions will be quite faster. Recovering binary data after that already will be very difficult. Someone will really need to have high interest in your data to spend the effort and time recovering these.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an NVMe storage device, then you can securely erase all data with the `nvme-cli` utility:

1. Boot the computer with an Ubuntu installation USB and choose “Try Ubuntu”
2. Open Terminal
3. Erase the encryption key for the flash modules:

   ```
   sudo nvme format -s2 /dev/nvme0n1
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `nvme0n1` with the actual device you wish to clear.</sup>
4. TRIM and zero the flash modules:

   ```
   sudo blkdiscard /dev/nvme0n1
   ```

After this is done, it is pretty much impossible to get any data back.