# Is the key acquired from running gpg --export-secret-key encrypted or cleartext?

Tags: security, gnupg

[How to share one PGP key on multiple machines](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32438/how-to-share-one-pgp-key-on-multiple-machines/32488#32488) details how to export your gpg secret key into a file with `gpg --export-secret-key -a > secretkey.asc`.  What the answer does *not* state is whether the keyfile created is encrypted with your pass-phrase or clear-text.

Is the key-file encrypted or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you import a key created by the `--export-secret-key` option, you get both the public & private keys; however, just like before you'll need the passphrase in order to use the private key. This is shown in the fact that you do not need your passphrase to run `gpg --export-secret-key -a`, and therefore the secret key never gets decrypted.

Personally, I would make sure to encrypt such an exported key again (perhaps symmetrically, with a long unique passphrase) if I was transporting or storing it.

Comment: This answer does not convince me. The fact that I do not need a passphrase to export again might just mean that the key is now stored unencrypted.

Comment: `you do not need your passphrase to run gpg --export-secret-key -a` this is not true